MS Graph: Messages are stuck in draft after sending them in under 0.2% of all deliveries
we are using microsoft graph api (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php version: 1.110.0) to connect to our customers office365 accounts (> 100k messages each day. It is a professional property management CRM which uses office365 over an MS application). We are using the ms graph api from our backend which is hosted on an aws ec2.
We perform the following actions:

Creating the message as a draft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
(optional) Add attachments to this message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
Get the message to store the original EML file (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
Send the message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

None of the addressed functions throws an exception in our scenario (only HTTP Code 2xx). In 99,8% of all deliveries there is no problem: email is added to draft folder and it is moved from draft so send items after that. In 0.2% of all cases (and especially if there are more deliveries with attachments at the same time for one customer) the email is not moved to send folder and stays in drafts. The weird fact about this: the message was send and the receiver gets it. Only the "move action" was not performed. So the message do not appear in send folder but in drafts what should be impossible at all.
I found a few people via google who reported this bug as well in boards outside stackoverflow. Is there anybody who has an advice what we can do here? We think, we cannot refactor our code to send a message directly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as there is no possibility to get the message eml file here (we need the messageId to perform the GET-action).
Thank you very much for any help.

Message Sends are asynchronous hence why you get a 202 Accepted which means the server accepted your request but it hasn't actioned it at that point. What then happens after that is really on the Service provider (Microsoft) they are the only ones that could tell you if there is a specific error being caused by a particular message eg a conflict, throttling or a bug. If your using createupload session your messages are going to be too big to do a one step send so you kind of stuck with the process you have.
